# How to force .env variables update in a nuxt project?

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js

hi!

I wonder if anyone knows if there is any way to force the update of the .env file.

First of all, every time that I modified my .env variables, the changes were happening right away but now I started using the next build configuration:

```
  build: {
    hardSource: true,
    cache: true,
    parallel: true,
  }
```

And ever since I started using those experimental features, the .env variables do not seem to get updated after I update one value in my .env file.

In my project, I develop the API in one machine and the front end on other machine (Just for convenience), so, sometimes my machine has the next IP address: 192.168.100.100 and sometimes 192.168.100.101, etc.

My project uses the environment variable (in the .env file)

```
API_URL=http://192.168.100.100:4100
BASE_URL=http://localhost:4200
```

So, when the local IP address of the first machine changes, I have to update the .env file.
The problem now is that even after killing the app, deleting .nuxt folder and running `npm run dev` I still see the API requests having the previous IP address.

### Solutions?

I have thought of disabling the cache and hardSource configurations but they are really helpful to me and the IP changes are not that often, but once in a while I have to update other variable, so that's not a solution for me.

I have also thought of disabling DHCP on my other machine and assigning it a fixed local IP address, but that is not ideal for me, although I think I will do that for now, hoping that in the future I get to know a better way of updating the environment variables (Because sooner or later I will need to update another variable that has nothing to do with the IP address)

I'd like to know if there is a way to force the .env variables to be updated in a nuxt project with hardSource, cache and parallel set to true.

Comment: Why is removing the DHCP such a big deal?

Comment: It's not a big deal. I actually used DHCP with a manual address. The problem is that it doesn't fix the problem. I could need to update other environment variable and it won't be updated immediately.

Comment: HI Have you solved this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76960199/how-to-update-env-variable-on-build-time-in-nuxt-3

I think i have a similar issue. Please help me guys