# How to update .env variable on build time in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am working on nuxt 3 project and I want to update the .env variable value and need to use that updated value on `nuxt.config.ts` file to generate the build with staging API URL

I have set the `NUXT_MODE=development` inside the `.env` file and want to update the value `development` to `staging` when I run `npm run generate_staging`

I have added the new script to package.json file `"generate_staging": "NUXT_MODE=staging nuxt generate --max-old-space-size=80096",`

I have set the `NUXT_MODE=staging` and when we run `npm run generate_staging`, it seems `nuxt.config.ts` file returns still use the old value of NUXT_MODE=development and generate the build for development.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 nuxt generate",
    "generate_staging": "NUXT_MODE=staging nuxt generate --max-old-space-size=80096",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "element-plus": "^2.2.27"
  }
}
```

**.env file**

```js
NUXT_MODE=development
NUXT_BASE=http://localhost:3000/
NUXT_API_BASE=http://localhost:3001/

NUXT_STAGING_BASE=http://my-staging-url/
NUXT_STAGING_API_BASE=http://my-staging-api-url/
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
const appEnv = process.env.NUXT_MODE || 'development'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: false,
    experimental: { payloadExtraction: false },
    modules: [
    ],
    runtimeConfig: {
        target: "static",
        public: {
            apiBase: appEnv == "staging" ? process.env.NUXT_STAGING_API_BASE : process.env.NUXT_API_BASE,
        }
    },
})
```

Please help me on this OR suggest to me the best approach to make a build for development and staging without changing the API URL manually each time.

### Thank you!

Comment: @everyone Please help me to get the solution to this..